# Created child process with `clone()`. Why does `wait()` not wait for it to terminate?

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run some code inside a separate UTS namespace, and I've been trying to do it in C.

I have a parent function with the following code:

```c
void run (char **args, int arglen) {
    printf("[*] Starting PID: %d\n", getpid());

    int i=1;
    cmd = concat_args(args, arglen);

    pid_t child_pid = clone(child_container, child_stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWPID, NULL);

    int status;
    wait(&status);
    printf("[*] Exit code: %d", status);
    return;
}
```

which creates a new process and SHOULD wait for it to finish its execution.

The child has the following code:

```c
void child_container () {
    printf("This is the container!\n");
    printf("[*] Child PID: %d\n", getpid());
    system(cmd);
    printf("test\n");
}
```

and I'd like to run any command before the parent shutting up.
The problem is that some commands (e.g. `/bin/ls`) manage to execute, other (slower) commands (e.g. `/bin/sh`) are shut down by the end of parent.

Since I used a wait function, I can't understand why the execution is stopping.

I tried using a sleep in the parent after the clone, and it delays the end of the program. This should mean that the problem is that the parent doesn't wait for its child.

I tried both wait and waitpid, but the process still ended.

Can the problem be the spawn of a new process (`/bin/sh`)? How can I fix?

**Edit**:

This should be a reproducible example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 0x3ff
#define STACK_SIZE 8192

static char child_stack[STACK_SIZE];
char *cmd;

char *concat_args(char **args, int arglen);
void child_container ();
void parse_command(char *cmd, char **args, int argc);
void run (char **args, int arglen);

char *concat_args(char **args, int arglen) {
    char *cmd = (char *)malloc((BUF_SIZE+1)*sizeof(char));
    memset(cmd, 0, BUF_SIZE+1);
    strncat(cmd, args[0], BUF_SIZE);
    for (int i=1; i<arglen; i++) {
        strncat(cmd, " ", BUF_SIZE);
        strncat(cmd, args[i], BUF_SIZE);
    }
    return cmd;
}

void run (char **args, int arglen) {
    printf("[*] Starting PID: %d\n", getpid());

    int i=1;
    cmd = concat_args(args, arglen);

    pid_t child_pid = clone(child_container, child_stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWPID, NULL);
    sleep(1);
    int status, e_code;
    e_code = wait(&status);
    if (e_code == -1) {
        perror("wait");
    }
    printf("[*] Exit code: %d\n[*] Status: %d\n", e_code, status);
    return;
}

void child_container () {
    printf("This is the container!\n");
    printf("[*] Child PID: %d\n", getpid());
    system(cmd);
    printf("test\n");
}

void parse_command(char *cmd, char **args, int argc) {
    if (!strcmp(cmd, "run")) {
        run(args, argc-2);
    } else {
        error("No such command!");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const char *format = "./container run [cmd] [args]";
    if (argc < 3) {
        error("Wrong format!\nThe commands must be formatted in the following way:\t./container run [cmd] [args]");
        return 0;
    }

    char *cmd = argv[1];
    char **args = &argv[2];

    parse_command(cmd, args, argc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what [`wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) *returns*? Have you checked that [`clone`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) itself succeeds? Both `CLONE_NEWPID` and `CLONE_NEWUTS` requires admin privileges, do you run your program with elelvated privileges?

Comment: Exit code is -1, status is always a big number (never the same). I'm running the process as root

Comment: If `wait` returns `-1` that means it has failed and you should check `errno` what happened. For example `if (wait(&status) == -1) { perror("wait"); }`

Comment: Create a [mre] by adding a `main` function that calls `run` in a way to reproduce the problem, preferably using hard-coded data.

Comment: It says "wait: No child processes"... while the child process is printing its information

Comment: Perhaps related to you creating a new PID namespace? Why do you even do that? And why do you create a new UTS namespace? What problem is that supposed to solve? This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://itnext.io/container-from-scratch-348838574160) to make containers. Unfortunately I never tried Go, so I'm using C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract from man page of clone

> **The child termination signal**
> When  the  child process terminates, a signal may be sent to the parent.  The termination signal is specified in the low
> byte of flags (**clone**()) or in cl_args.exit_signal (**clone3**()).  If this  signal  is  specified  as  anything  other  than
> **SIGCHLD**,  then  the  parent process must specify the __WALL or __WCLONE options when waiting for the child with **wait**(2).
> If no signal (i.e., zero) is specified, then the parent process is not signaled when the child terminates.

So, answer is clear. You did not specify a signal, so you are not notified when your child terminates, so wait has nothing to wait.

```c
    pid_t child_pid = clone(child_container, child_stack+STACK_SIZE, CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWPID | SIGCHLD, NULL);
```

should solve the problem (at least, without it, you have no chance to have wait working)